# Get evey finger position dragged from left to right

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

I'm really struggling on an Android app in Phonegap and JQuery.

All I want to do is, as I drag my finger from left to right, I want to be able to output to screen exactly what my x position is.

I've played around with touchstart and touchmove but that only seems to output the start position when I touch the screen and the final position when I take my finger off the screen.

It doesn't seem to be updating the exact positions as I move my finger.

I need it to update the screen with every x coordinate as my finger slides.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Wait, using jQuery or jQuery Mobile for your Android app? jQuery Mobile has vmousemove event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you considered creating a custom view that does this purpose? by overriding onTouchEvent you can get the exact x and y coordinates every time a touch event (finger down, finger up, finger move) occurs.

Comment: How would I do this? I'm using PhoneGap.